# When Select France Language in Google Translate Price Formatting Different in cart page in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, translate, conditional-loading, store-language

I set the google translate to translate language in magento 1.9, but in the cart page for some products, the currency symbol was not changed.

> Select Language France

[image]

> Select Language English

[image]

any one can help me for this in magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

The currency is a concept that belongs to how your storeview is configured, and not a regular text that goes through the translation process.

You can still have the website text translated to English and products displayed with USD and still be a valid configuration.

But what I think you need, is a **['currency switcher'](https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/)**

Comment: okay let me try this one thank you

Comment: hi there, any luck?